# Add word & number count at start of listbox items in VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a multi-line textbox `textbox1` and want to add the content to `listbox1`, but before each item I need to add "wordX=" where "X" is the item number.

Example of `textbox1`:

> bob
>   gear
>   dog
>   etc.

Then `listbox1` should have:

> word1=bob
>   word2=gear
>   word3=dog
>   etc.

Currently I am using the line below to copy the `textbox3` content to `listbox1` but can't find how to add "word" and the proper number.

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox3.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used to complete what you wanted.

```
Dim tbLines As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
ListBox1.Items.Clear()

For i As Integer = 1 To tbLines.Length
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange({"word" & i & "=" & tbLines(i - 1).Trim})
Next
```

I split the text box using the `vbNewLine` separator as you did. I then go through each index in that array to concatenate the string "word" with the `i` (current index) integer. I finish off with concatenating the "=" as well as the trimmed value in the listbox.